# Pandas difference between row by multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, difference

So im having this challenge right now. I have a pandas df(with over 30 million rows) that looks like follows:

```
Name  | State | Date       | Income
____________________________________
Name1 | Tx    | 2019-01-26 | $100
Name2 | CA    | 2019-01-26 | $500
Name3 | LA    | 2019-01-26 | $200
Name1 | Tx    | 2019-02-26 | $110
Name2 | CA    | 2019-02-26 | $520
Name3 | LA    | 2019-02-26 | $210
```

As you can see, i have 2 columns to identify a person (his name and State), then 1 column for a timestamp (which varies over month), what I'm trying to achieve is to get the difference between months for every person, resulting in something like:

```
Name  | State | Date       | Income | Variation
____________________________________
Name1 | Tx    | 2019-01-26 | $100   |  NaN
Name2 | CA    | 2019-01-26 | $500   |  NaN
Name3 | LA    | 2019-01-26 | $200   |  NaN
Name1 | Tx    | 2019-02-26 | $110   |  10
Name2 | CA    | 2019-02-26 | $480   | -20
Name3 | LA    | 2019-02-26 | $210   |  10
```

And so on for the incoming months
I found the diff function, but i don't know how to specify that must match the same name and state but for the previous month

Comment: `df.groupby('State')['Income'].diff()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort by `Date`, and use a groupby transform on `['Name', 'State']`. This solution should work:

```
df['Variation'] = (df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Name', 'State'])['Income']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.diff()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work like a charm:

```
df['Variation'] = df.groupby('State')['Income'].diff()
```